# Where to change orientation restrcitions in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, orientation

For an iOS 7 app, I have a storyboard with a simple UINavigateController and a ViewController. I remember having limited the navigation and/or view controller to Landscape, and now I can't find anymore where I had changed this. I am not talking about the appearance of the controller on the Interface Builder screen, but the supported orientations. I tried to override it in the code, but it doesn't help.

Any clue where to find this again ? Thanks.

Comment: Show the methods you have overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change/restrict the types of orientations of your app from your Interface Builder, Try these steps.

1. Open up your project navigator and click on your project.
2. You will see a screen like this.
   [image]
3. Under the general tab, See the Deployment Info Options. There you check/uncheck the types of orientations you want to keep or not.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict the orientation on iPhone you can easily click the project on the navigator and when you click, go on the general page. Below you can uncheck the orientations you don't want.

- Just keep in mind, you cant lock orientations for an iPad app. An iPad app should support all the orientations. (based on the apple Human Interface Guidelines)